# How to write VBA code for the table

Tags: vba, excel

```
(T,P)   300     310    320   330   340   350    F
3400    1       1      1     1     1     1  
3300    1       1      1     1     1     1  
3200    1       1    0.95   0.95  0.95  0.9 
3100    1     0.95   0.9    0.85  0.85  0.8 
3000    0.95  0.9    0.85   0.82  0.81  0.8 
2900    0.9   0.85   0.8    0.8   0.75  0.73    
2800    0.85  0.8    0.75   0.73  0.72  0.7 
psia
```

Currently I have this table. The goal is to input temp (for instance, 320 F), then search the 1st liquid fraction change from 1 to 0.95, and use the bisection method to find out the pressure. The following is my code. They are not working. I really need someone to correct it for me. Thanks a lot!

```
Sub Linear()
Dim aksheet As Worksheet
Set aksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim c       As Long
Dim Tin As Double
Dim Pout As Double
With aksheet
    LastRow = aksheet.Range("A9").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = aksheet.Range("H1").End(xlToLeft).Column
'input temperature
Tin = aksheet.Range("B25").Value
itemp = 0
For i = 1 To LastCol - 1
    T(i) = Cells(1, i + 1).Value
Next
If Tin - T(6) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Input temperature is too high")
ElseIf Tin - T(1) < 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Input Temperature is too low")
End If

FirstRow = 1
    For c = FirstRow To LastRow
        If Tin = T(i) And .Cells(c, i).Value < 1 Then
            interp = (0.99, .Cells (c,i),.Cells(c+1,i),.Cells(c,1),.Cells(c+1,1))
        End If
    Next c
End With
Range("B30").Value = Pb
End Sub
Function interp(Xin, T1, T2, P1, P2) As Double
interp = P1 + (P2 - P1) * (Tin - T1) / (T2 - T1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code

Comment: What exactly isn't working here? What's the error message you are receiving? It does look like you haven't initialized the array `T`. Adding `Dim T() As Variant` and `ReDim T(1 To LastCol - 1)` may solve your problem.

Comment: I actually have no clue after finishing first EndIf. I need some clues how to write the coding. My goal is to use the interp function to find the associated pressure. For instance, at 320 F, when the liquid frac changes 1 to 0.95, there are two pressures 3300 and 3200 psia associated. I want to include these two pressure in the equation and find out the associated pressure if my liquid fraction is 0.99.

Comment: The macro shows that "Sub or function not defined". I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: @tlin Another issue may be that you have an undefined variable in your `interp` function, `Tin`. You will need to define it as a global variable, redefine it in the function, or pass it in as an argument (unless it's supposed to be `Xin`.)

Comment: Still not working! Hope someone could help me do a complete thorough fix.